# Shopify collect orders with rest API error

Tags: shopify

I am trying to get the Shopify orders list with the latest version of rest pagination API. There are totally of 1000 orders. I set a limit of 200. First page of API hit is working properly. While I am hitting the second page with page info I am getting error as below. Can you help me please regarding this.

Rest API URL: GET https://the-commerce-shop-1.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?limit=200&page_info=eyJzdGF0dXMiOiJhbnkiLCJsYXN0X2lkIjoxODY4Njk3NjY1NTkxLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMjAxOS0xMS0yNSAwOTozNjo1OSIsImRpcmVjdGlvbiI6Im5leHQifQ&status=any

Error: Message: Client error: `GET https://the-commerce-shop-1.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?limit=200&page_info=eyJzdGF0dXMiOiJhbnkiLCJsYXN0X2lkIjoxODY4Njk3NjY1NTkxLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMjAxOS0xMS0yNSAwOTozNjo1OSIsImRpcmVjdGlvbiI6Im5leHQifQ&status=any` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{\"errors\":{\"status\":\"status cannot be passed when page_info is present. See https:\/\/help.shopify.com\/api\/guides\/pag (truncated...)\n, Line: 113"

Answer (score 2):

First you ask for orders with nothing but the status you want and a limit. That initates the paging.

Once you are through your first 200 orders, you no longer call the endpoint with status or limit, you simply use paging.

That works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the your valuable answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, you are free to accept answers with a click of appreciation too. Thanks!